# Ruby on Rails: Multiple conditions in rails based in different fields using like

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, search, sql-like

I have a entity in my database that have multiple fields.
I need search in this entity based if a certain input it's contained in certain fields, by example

**Entity Car**

- model_name
- owner

I want search like this (a pseudo sql idea)

```
 Select * FROM Car WHERE (LIKE model_name = "%maz%" OR LIKE owner = "%maz%")
```

I've tried with the find method but it's not work

```
searched_string = "%maz%"
Car.find(:all, :conditions => {model_name: searched_string, owner: searched_string})
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `conditions` option in an `ActiveRecord` query, the resulting SQL will be generated for an exact match. Additionally, each condition you add will be joined using an `AND`, not an `OR`.

That being said, the SQL generated by your query above likely looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM Car WHERE (model_name = "%maz%" AND owner = "%maz%")`

To get the query you are looking for, you'll have to hand-write the SQL for the `WHERE` clause.

`Car.where("model_name ILIKE :q OR owner ILIKE :q", q: "%maz%")`

NOTE: I'm using the more modern `ActiveRecord` syntax above.

---

Some good news is that Rails 5 will include [support for "or" queries](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052).

Comment: Great! Glad it worked. Regarding the case-insensitive search, you'll notice that I used the `ILIKE` keyword rather than the `LIKE` keyword-- this is exactly for doing a case-insensitive search. So use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE` and you'll be good.